# Insert a character to a column of a data table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table which has a date field that's not in the right format, its currently in YYYYMMDD (20181201) format and I wish to change it to YYYY-MM-DD (2018-12-01) by inserting "-" between the year, month and day.

```
> claim_info[, .SD[5,3]]
   FILL_MONTH
1:   20180501
```

Comment: IF `FILL_MONTH` is not a character field, you will need to use `as.character(FILL_Month)` before using JohnCoene's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some reason you wanted to keep it as a character type rather than converting to date:

```
gsub("20181009",pattern = "(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})",replacement = "\\1-\\2-\\3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is how you can change your dates to a `Date` class.

```
# generating sample data
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:2,
  date = c("20180101", "20180102")
)

# format the date
(df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format = "%Y%m%d"))
```

A good resource for this kind of questions= is the documentation of `?strptime`.